Checking if a TeX definition already exists
I know, that there are other solutions.
Question is: How may I get the #1 into the place of the dots in this example?
\TeX
    
    \def\check#1{\ifx#1\undefined ... is undefined\else now ... is defined\fi}
    \check{\newtest}
    
    \def\newtest{Date \the\year-\the\month-\the\day}
    
    \check{\newtest}
    
    \newtest
    \bye


Try {\tt\string#1}?

@Stephen Works! Thanks.
